# Cannot enable File History service: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I'm trying to enable File History on my desktop computer every time I try to turn it on, I get the following error:

```
Could not enable File History: The parameter is incorrect.
```

[image: Parameter Incorrect error dialog]

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what the problem is. I've looked at EventVwr and found zero logs under:

- `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-FileHistory-Engine%4BackupLog.evtx`
- `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-FileHistory-Core%4WHC.evtx`

I also looked under the following logs and nothing seemed related to the error, near as I could tell:

- `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Application.evtx`
- `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx`

I've already ensured that both the `File History Service` and `Windows Search` services are both enabled.

What are my next steps to try to track this error down?

#### Update 1/22/2022

I used ProcessMonitor and ProcessExplorer to track down the process behind the dialog: explorer.exe. Using ProcessMonitor, I found a `INVALID_PARAMTER` error:

[image: error event dialog]

In addition, I tried doing a regular Backup and found errors that led me to believe that an old Windows Home Server might be causing issues. I removed the home server shares from my libraries (and other user accounts on the computer), but still File History won't enable.

Comment: It a message to a programmer. It just means a Windows function was called and it saying you called me wrong to the programmer. Find the process in Task Manager and right click it and choose Create Dump File. You'll need to upload it somewhere for me to download without me creating an account there. I'll be examining it with WinDbg - if you want to try https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/brief-introduction-to-windows-debugger.html

Comment: Let Windows try to fix it, using SFC and DISM: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e

Comment: Do you have an external drive plugged in?  Do you have a volume or partition that is visible to windows but doesn't have a file system that windows can read?  Also, run chkdsk on all of your volumes.

Comment: I recently plugged in a 6TB external drive that's NTFS formatted. It shows up in `Control Panel > System and Security > File History`. I'll try running `chkdsk` and see if that helps.

Comment: Running SFC and DISM found one problem with `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\\mscormmc.dll`. However, the problem persists.

Comment: Does this information help? https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-history-parameter-is-incorrect-error/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @w32sh. Unlike that article, I cannot find any log entries and the `config.xml` files never get created. I haven't renamed my machine anytime recently, but I do use junction points to put `c:\Users` on to a larger, HDD `D:` drive. I've played around with my libraries to make sure they didn't point at the junction point (that seems to affect File History negatively, from what I've read) but so far, no success, and I get the same error.

Comment: @Spig: After renaming the two XML files, reconfigure File History. Restart the File History service. Hopefully, that should recreate the two XML files.

Comment: Thanks @w32sh for sticking with me. The XML files never exist. I tried creating them manually and when I try to turn on File History, the files get deleted, but never recreated. I also turned on the File History service (it wasn't started) but it keeps shutting down. Again, nothing in the logs.